# Encrypt App.config file automatically during build process

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, msbuild, windows-installer

Currently, my application automatically encrypts its own App.config file the first time the application is launched.

I'm using the `ConfigurationManager` class as demonstrated in this article:

- [Encrypting Passwords in a .NET app.config File](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx)

**Now I want the App.config to already be encrypted before the application launches the first time.**

Reason why is that I have added an installer to my solution and I don't want an installer that drops an un-encrypted App.config.  I want the process to be automated.

*(only thing I came up with so far is attaching an .exe to the Post-Build Event, but isn't there a more straight forward way?)*

Comment: An external tool scheduled as a pre-build event is the best approach. This way app.config is already encrypted when your setup project is built.

Comment: I'm using a Windows Setup Project, so I don't know how to set a Pre-Build Event for the setup project.  Therefore, I thought about calling the console app from the Post-Build Event of the Primary Output project.  However, I plan to use Cruise Control and call my console app prior to building the setup project, which is basically what you are suggesting.  Thanks.

Comment: Most Visual Studio projects have pre-build events. What project type are you using?

Comment: If you encrypt the app.config on the machine doing the build, won't that mean that it can only be decrypted on that machine.  So if you later install it on a different machine, how could it decrypt it?

Comment: @Cosmin Pirvu: Windows Setup Project type.

Comment: @Stephen McDaniel: yep, that's correct! :(  So instead I tried an approach that encrypts the app.config on the user's PC during installation (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/ProtectedConfigWinApps.aspx).  However, it's throwing an exception.  I've looked up securing the app.config file for WinForms applications, and I have found no good solutions.  I must be an idiot.

Comment: What kind of data are you needing to secure in your app.config.  If you just want to hide it, perhaps you could move into your actual C# code.  Not bullet-proof but nothing will be.  If you want help with the new exception, either edit your question with the details or consider asking a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Option:** Using built in MSBuild [Exec Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) execute own utility program which is able to encrypt configuration file.

**Second Option:** Own MSBuild task

I believe you can write a simple `MSBuild` Task which will find `App.Config` file and then encrypt it whilst Solution build.

1. Create a new MSBuild Targets like `EncryptConfig.targets`
2. Update `csproj` file by  `<Import Project="EncryptConfig.targets" />`
3. Add `DependsOnTargets` for standard `AfterBuild` targets in csproj:

```xml
 <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="EncryptConfig.targets" />
```

4) Write own task and execute it in `EncryptConfig.targets`

How-to write own task:

- [Task Writing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx)
- [An MSBuild Task to run C# code](http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2008/09/02/an-msbuild-task-to-run-c-code.aspx)

Comment: +1 - You can also execute your own utility .exe from PostBuildEvent (which is what I ended up doing for now).  Example: `<PostBuildEvent>if $(ConfigurationName) == Release $(TargetDir)\AppConfigEncryptor.exe $(TargetPath)</PostBuildEvent>`

Answer (score 1):

You can code the encryption in the same app you want to deploy. Execute it with a main args switch. This way the PostBuild event can run your own app with the switch that encrypts the config file. This way you can keep all functional context of the encryption task dedicated with your app (e.g. if you want to encrypt different sections for different apps). I use precompiler directives in the app to do the encryption only for Releases. I guess doing this in the PostBuild event like suggested above is more efficient.